# How to have a form submit a perimeter value for a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am looking to have the input of a form submit a perimeter value to a javascript function and have the function called once the submit button is clicked. I have limited knowledge on how to approach this so any help is greatly appreciated. P.S. I had to take off the opening bracket to the submit button so everything will display.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="numbervalue" value="value" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" onsubmit="numbervalue()">
```

Answer (score 0):

put onsumbit in form tag and try, [sample code](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_onsubmit)

```
<form name="frm1" action="your.htm" onsubmit="numbervalue()">
<input type="text" name="name" id="numbervalue" value="value" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use onclick event for the button

```
 <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="numbervalue();">
```

or in form,

```
 <form id="id1" name="id1" method="post" onsubmit="numbervalue();"  action="index.html" >
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing onsubmit can be used in  not in  tag and can also call javascript function with or without parameters
For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function numbervalue()
{
 alert("Welcome " + document.forms["frm1"]["fname"].value + "!")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frm1" action="submit.htm" onsubmit="numbervalue()">
<input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice and example, it makes much more sense now.